# Sinatra error -- JSON::ParserError - 784: unexpected token

Tags: angularjs, json, ruby, sinatra

I have an api in Sinatra (Mongodb). I am trying to write some data with the POST method from very small application written in Angularjs. data I am trying to send is 'aplication/x-www-form-urlencoded'. For some reason I keep getting the error:

```
JSON::ParserError - 784: unexpected token at 'id=111&name=Bruce&city=LA&address=City1':
```

I can see that there is some data encoded in url, but Sinatra does not read it correctly.

Sinatra:

```
post '/companies' do
  company=JSON.parse(request.body.read)
  company = Company.new(company)
end
```

AngularJs script:

```
var formApp = angular.module('formApp', []);
function formController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.processForm = function() {
        $http({
            method  : 'POST',
            url     : 'http://localhost:4567/api/v1/companies',
            data    : $.param($scope.formData),  // pass in data as strings
            headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        })
            .success(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                if (!data.success) {
                    // if not successful, bind errors to error variables
                    $scope.errorName = data.errors.name;
                    $scope.errorSuperhero = data.errors.superheroAlias;
                } else {
                    // if successful, bind success message to message
                    $scope.message = data.message;
                                $scope.errorName = '';
                    $scope.errorSuperhero = '';
                }
            });
    };
}
```

I am calling the function formData with the button after the form is completed in HTML:

```
body ng-app="formApp" ng-controller="formController">
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

    <!-- PAGE TITLE -->
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tower"></span> Submitting Forms with Angular</h1>
    </div>

    <!-- SHOW ERROR/SUCCESS MESSAGES -->
    <div id="messages" class="well" ng-show="message">{{ message }}</div>

    <!-- FORM -->
    <form ng-submit="processForm()">


        <div id="superhero-group" class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errorSuperhero }">
            <label>ID</label>
            <input type="text" name="id" class="form-control" placeholder="Caped Crusader" ng-model="formData.id">
            <span class="help-block" ng-show="errorSuperhero">{{ errorSuperhero }}</span>
        </div>  


        <div id="name-group" class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errorName }">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Bruce Wayne" ng-model="formData.name">
                        <span class="help-block" ng-show="errorName">{{ errorName }}</span>
        </div>

        <!-- SUPERHERO NAME -->
        <div id="superhero-group" class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errorSuperhero }">
            <label>City</label>
            <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control" placeholder="Caped Crusader" ng-model="formData.city">
            <span class="help-block" ng-show="errorSuperhero">{{ errorSuperhero }}</span>
        </div>

                <div id="superhero-group" class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errorSuperhero }">
            <label>Address</label>
            <input type="text" name="address" class="form-control" placeholder="Caped Crusader" ng-model="formData.address">
            <span class="help-block" ng-show="errorSuperhero">{{ errorSuperhero }}</span>
        </div>

        <!-- SUBMIT BUTTON -->
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></span> Submit!
        </button>
    </form>

    <!-- SHOW DATA FROM INPUTS AS THEY ARE BEING TYPED -->
    <pre>
        {{ formData }}
    </pre>

</div>
```

Comment: You're trying to parse JSON but that string does not look like JSON. Can you post the full string of what you're trying to parse?

Comment: I have edited the post with angularjs script and html form, if you would like to see anything else, please just say

Comment: The AngularJS code is old an obsolete. For more information, see [Why are angular $http success/error methods deprecated? Removed from v1.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angular-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/35331339#35331339).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because the AngularJS code is sending data in URL encoded form. To POST data as a [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) string:

```
var formApp = angular.module('formApp', []);
function formController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.processForm = function() {
        $http({
            method  : 'POST',
            url     : 'http://localhost:4567/api/v1/companies',
            ̶d̶a̶t̶a̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶:̶ ̶$̶.̶p̶a̶r̶a̶m̶(̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶f̶o̶r̶m̶D̶a̶t̶a̶)̶,̶ ̶ ̶/̶/̶ ̶p̶a̶s̶s̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶d̶a̶t̶a̶ ̶a̶s̶ ̶s̶t̶r̶i̶n̶g̶s̶
            data    : $scope.formData, //data automatically coded as JSON string
            ̶h̶e̶a̶d̶e̶r̶s̶ ̶:̶ ̶{̶ ̶'̶C̶o̶n̶t̶e̶n̶t̶-̶T̶y̶p̶e̶'̶:̶ ̶'̶a̶p̶p̶l̶i̶c̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶/̶x̶-̶w̶w̶w̶-̶f̶o̶r̶m̶-̶u̶r̶l̶e̶n̶c̶o̶d̶e̶d̶'̶ ̶}̶            
        })
            ̶.̶s̶u̶c̶c̶e̶s̶s̶(̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶(̶d̶a̶t̶a̶)̶ ̶{̶
            .then(function(response) {
                ̲v̲a̲r̲ ̲d̲a̲t̲a̲ ̲=̲ ̲r̲e̲s̲p̲o̲n̲s̲e̲.̲d̲a̲t̲a̲;̲
                console.log(data);
                if (!data.success) {
                    // if not successful, bind errors to error variables
                    $scope.errorName = data.errors.name;
                    $scope.errorSuperhero = data.errors.superheroAlias;
                } else {
                    // if successful, bind success message to message
                    $scope.message = data.message;
                                $scope.errorName = '';
                    $scope.errorSuperhero = '';
                }
            });
    };
}
```

The $http service automatically encodes JavaScript objects as JSON strings. The content type header is set to `application/json`.

The `.success` method is obsolete. Use `.then` instead. For more information, see [Why are angular $http success/error methods deprecated? Removed from v1.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angular-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/35331339#35331339).

Comment: Thanks for help, I did correction but I get 404 erroe in console without any xhanges on the server. Then I added headers as well and i got t200 OK, but my response error is: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data, then i change to params tab and i see: {"id":"99","name":"Bruce Lee","city":"Shangai","address":"MStreet"}:           ! I can see this double colon, I guess it is the reason of the error right?

Comment: It led me to the right answer so I accept this answer, thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to parse URL encoded data by passing it through a JSON parser. This will not work.

Try parsing `response.body` as a regular String rather than a JSON String.